# How to check and fix a component in a InnoSetup project?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm developing a InnoSetup project and I'm wondering how to always install a component (let's say 'Acrobat Reader') but don't allow to uncheck that item in the list of components.
I don't want the user uncheck it.

Comment: Yay for forcibly installing 3rd party commercial applications!

Comment: It was an example .. I need to install a set of common mandatory libraries ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, a component is selected when the selected installation type is listed in the [`Types`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection&anchor=Types) parameter of its entry. So if you list all the available installation types there, it will be selected always.

To disable the component so that users cannot modify its state, you need to include the [`fixed`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection&anchor=fixed) flag for the entry.

So to make a disabled, always selected component with default installation types (which are used when you don't specify your own installation types in the [`[Types]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection) section), you would write entry like this:

```
[Components]
Name: "main"; Description: "Main Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
```

---

In your comment you've asked how to disable a task entry. As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this and the only way I could come up with is doing this in code from the [`CurPageChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged) event:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Tasks]
Name: something; Description: "Install something"

[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // the ItemEnabled property uses a 0 based index for item access, so the following
  // code you can read as, if we have entered the tasks selection page, disable the
  // first tasks list item
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
    WizardForm.TasksList.ItemEnabled[0] := False;
end;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the action was defined as a Task, and a task does not have the 'fixed' flag. So I need to define a Component that has the flag. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to fix a task?

Comment: How can i check the item? I try with `Check:1` or `Check: True` but they cause a compilation error ..

Comment: I've added an example for how to disable task item. But I would prefer using commponents for this. To your second question, how to check which item ? A component or task ?

Comment: `[Tasks]` are for "do this", `[Components]` are for "install this".